# HTML - Two identical pieces of code running different outputs?

Tags: php, html

Just a fore note: I am messing around with HTML / CSS / PHP and MySQL. I do NOT have security in mind just yet.

I have 2 files, the first called page1.php and the second one called page2.php. Pretty simple, they both have a **navbar** which has some PHP code in it:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){
    echo "<li class='navbar-button' id='right-status'><a>Logged in as admin</a></li>\n";
    echo "<li class='navbar-button' id='right-change'><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></li>\n";
} else {
    echo "<li class='navbar-button' id='right-change'><a href='login.html'>Log In</a></li>";
}
```

It checks whether or not a current session data named 'loggedin' exists, if it does it shows "Logged in as admin - Log Out" on the navbar. If it cannot find this session data, it shows "Log In" on the navbar. When I load page1.php, on the navbar it shows "Logged in as admin - Log Out", however when I load page2.php it shows "Log In". These both have **identical** code, and i
m not sure why they produce different results. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but page2.php is not stored in the same folder as page1.php. Page1.php's directory is /page1.php. Page2.php's directory is /folder/page2.php.

Question 1: Do PHP sessions store data globally over every single file / folder in the entirety of the website? Or just in the root folder?

Question 2: Why does my code give different answers?

Thank you for your time in advance.

:)

**Edit:**

Sorry forgot to mention, page2.php was computer-generated using PHP.

Comment: Are you starting the session in both files?

Comment: @RossWilson Oh.... damn. I forgot to edit the computer-generated code to start the session. I feel like such a dumbass. Thank you for pointing out the obvious...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to start the session in my page2.php (computer-generated) as it's quite complicated and I must've just skipped over it. Thanks to RossWilson who pointed it out.